# How to solve $\log_{3}(x) = \log_{\frac{1}{3}}(x) + 8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, logarithms

I'm trying to solve $\log_{3}(x) = \log_{\frac{1}{3}}(x) + 8$.  I am getting x = 4 but the book gets x = 81.  What am I doing wrong? 
\begin{align*}
\log_{3}(x) & = \log_{\frac{1}{3}}(x) + 8\\
\log_{3}(x) & = \frac{\log_{3}(x)}{\log_{3}(\frac{1}{3})} + 8\\
\log_{3}(x) & = \frac{\log_{3}(x)}{-\log_{3}(3)} + 8\\
\log_{3}(x) & = \frac{\log_{3}(x)}{-1} + 8\\
\log_{3}(x) & = -\log_{3}(x) + 8\\
2\log_{3}(x) & =  8\\
\log_{3}(x) & =  4\\
x & =  4
\end{align*}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\log_{3}(x) = -\log_{3}(x) + 8$ does *not* imply $0 = 8$.

Comment: After your edit: $\log_3(x) = 4$ does not imply $x=4$.

Comment: Do you remember the definition of the logarithmic function? $$\log_{a}{x}=b\Longleftrightarrow a^b=x.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake:

It should be $$2\log_3x=8$$ or
$$\log_3x=4$$ or
$$\log_3x=\log_3{3^4},$$
which gives $x=81$.

Actually, in the first step you can use the following property.
$$\log_{a^{\beta}}x=\frac{1}{\beta}\log_ax,$$ where $a>0$, $a\neq1$, $x>0$ and $\beta\neq0$.

Since $\frac{1}{3}=3^{-1},$ we obtain $$\log_3x=-\log_3x+8$$ immediately.

Answer (score 1):

$\log_3 x=4\implies x=3^4=81,$ not $x=4$

Answer (score 1):

When you want to find the value of $~x~$ inside a logarithm function, first you have to make both side in term of logarithm first (convert four into a logarithm term) and then inverse it to find $~x~$ :

$\log_{3}(x) = 4(1)$  $\Leftarrow$ convert $~1~$ into logarithm base $~3~$

$\log_{3}(x) = 4.\log_{3}(3)$  $\Leftarrow$ raise $~4~$ as exponent

$\log_{3}(x) = \log_{3}(3^{4})$ $\Leftarrow$ inverse it using exponent function

$3^{\log_{3}(x)} = 3^{\log_{3}(3^{4})}$

$ x = 3^{4} = 81$

Answer (score 1):

First, $\log_{1/3}x = \log_{3}\frac{1}{x}$; hence,

$$ \log_{3}x - \log_{3} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)  = \log_{3} \left(\frac{x}{\frac{1}{x}} \right) = \log_{3}x^{2} = 8$$

which is equivalent to

$$ 3^{8} = \left( 3^{4} \right)^{2} = x^{2}.$$

And so,

$$x = 3^{4} = 81.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\log_3 (x)=\log_{1/3} (x)+8 $
$\iff \log_3 (x)=-\log_3 (x)+8$
$\iff 2\log_3 (x)=8$
$\iff \log_3 (x)=4$
$\implies x=3^4=81$